# Postgres type casting and parameter binding conflict

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1.
```

For this kind of query:

```
UPDATE user
 SET Email = 'fake.' || id::varchar || '@localhost'
 WHERE Email is not null and char_length(Email)>0 and removed=false and id in (:ids)
```

I run this query as native query like this:

```
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createSQLQuery(sql)
            .setParameterList("ids", ids)
            .executeUpdate()
        ;
```

Seems like `id::varchar` is confusing Hibernate or JDBC. Any way to escape this maybe? Pretty standard Postgres syntax for type casting. Don't like casting syntax and would prefer to use this type mapping.

Answer (score 3):

Use `concat()` which will automatically cast the ID:

```
UPDATE user
 SET Email = concat('fake.', id, '@localhost')
 WHERE Email is not null 
   and char_length(Email) > 0 
   and removed = false 
   and id in (:ids)
```

Alternatively use the standard CAST operator:

```
UPDATE user
 SET Email = 'fake.' || cast(id as text) || '@localhost'
 WHERE Email is not null 
   and char_length(Email) > 0 
   and removed = false 
   and id in (:ids)
```

Comment: Hm... Interesting that concat does casting automatically and lpad doesn't . And I really prefer this: `lpad(id::varchar, 8, '0')`, over this: `lpad(cast(id as varchar), 8, '0')`